# Reactive function giving error in Shiny framework R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to make a reactive plot with radio buttons in shiny. However, after using the reactive expressions I am not able to see any plot.

Here is the reproducible code of the complete app

```
# Loading libs
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(mapdata)
library(mapproj)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
    navbarPage("PageTitle",
        tabPanel("US-Data-Visualizer",
                sidebarPanel(tags$h2("Map Visualizer"), tags$h4("Visualize the counts on US map, state wise"),
                      radioButtons("radio_option", label = "Select from the following options:",
                          choices = list("Total Cases" = "state$TOTAL.CASES", "New Cases" = "state$NEW.CASES",
                              "Active Cases" = "state$ACTIVE.CASES", "Total Deaths" = "state$TOTAL.DEATHS", 
                              "New Deaths" = "state$NEW.DEATHS", "Total Tests" = "state$TOTAL.TESTS"), 
                              selected = "state$TOTAL.CASES")),
                mainPanel(plotOutput("us_cases"))))
) #close fluid page

server <- function(input, output){
  state <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spriyansh/ShinyApps/master/datasets/USA_State_Wise_Data.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
  us_geo_data <- map_data("county")
  reactive_df <- reactive({
    us_geo_data <- data.table(us_geo_data)
    covid_map <- data.frame(state_names=unique(us_geo_data$region),
    values = input$radio_option)
    setkey(us_geo_data,region)
    covid_map <- data.table(covid_map)
    setkey(covid_map,state_names)
    map.df <- us_geo_data[covid_map]})
  output$us_cases <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(reactive_df()$map.df,
           aes(x = reactive_df()$map.df$long, y = reactive_df()$map.df$lat,
               group = reactive_df()$map.df$group,fill = reactive_df()$covid_map$values)) + 
      geom_polygon(alpha = 0.8) + coord_map() 
  )}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, there is no need for `reactive_option()$opt`, `reactive_option()` is enough. Same thing for `reactive_df()$manipulated_df`

Comment: The code is running fine, but there is no display of plot

Comment: I think you don't need the line with `isolate`. Remove it and try `output$plot <- renderPlot({ggplot(reactive_df())})` but don't forget to use `aes` in `ggplot` and to add `geom_line`, or `geom_point` or something else

Comment: Yes, I have tried. And attached the actual code(drive link) in the question. It would be really helpful if you can give it a read.

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not reproducible because there is no data and no `library` calls. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to make a minimal, reproducible example.

**Edit following OP's edit:**

The problem is that you try to return different dataframes from `reactive_df`, which is impossible. You should instead merge `covid_map` and `state_names` together, so that all the information you need is in `map.df`, which is returned by `reactive` since it is the last action. Then, you can remove the long expressions in `ggplot`.

There was also a problem with the choices in `radioButtons`. It is better to only put the column names as choices and then to call filter the data with these column names with `state[[input$radio_option]]`.

Here's your code:

```
# Loading libs
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(mapdata)
library(mapproj)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

state <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spriyansh/ShinyApps/master/datasets/USA_State_Wise_Data.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
us_geo_data <- map_data("county")

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
  navbarPage(
    "PageTitle",
    tabPanel(
      "US-Data-Visualizer",
      sidebarPanel(
        tags$h2("Map Visualizer"), tags$h4("Visualize the counts on US map, state wise"),
        radioButtons("radio_option",
          label = "Select from the following options:",
          choices = list(
            "Total Cases" = "TOTAL.CASES", "New Cases" = "NEW.CASES",
            "Active Cases" = "ACTIVE.CASES", "Total Deaths" = "TOTAL.DEATHS",
            "New Deaths" = "NEW.DEATHS", "Total Tests" = "TOTAL.TESTS"
          ),
          selected = "TOTAL.CASES"
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("us_cases"))
    )
  )
) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output) {

  reactive_df <- reactive({
    us_geo_data <- data.table(us_geo_data)
    covid_map <- data.frame(
      state_names = unique(us_geo_data$region),
      values = state[[input$radio_option]]
    )
    setkey(us_geo_data, region)
    covid_map <- data.table(covid_map)
    setkey(covid_map, state_names)
    map.df <- dplyr::left_join(us_geo_data, covid_map, by = c("region" = "state_names"))
  })
  output$us_cases <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(
      reactive_df(),
      aes(
        x = long, y = lat,
        group = group, fill = values
      )
    ) +
      geom_polygon(alpha = 0.8) +
      coord_map()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi! I have edited the question and have added the reproducible code.